# Why do these 2 pieces of code not behave identically?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Why do these following functions not work the same ? The first one is doing a proper string split but the second one seems to keep adding "" forever, creating an infinite list

Right code:

```
my_split :: [Char]->Char->[[Char]]
my_split [] _ = [[]]
my_split lista y
    | notElem y lista=[lista]
    | otherwise=isMatch:(my_split rest y)
    where 
            isMatch=takeWhile (/=y) lista
            rest=tail $ dropWhile (/=y) lista
```

Bad Code :

```
my_split :: [Char]->Char->[[Char]]
my_split [] _ = [[]]
my_split lista y
    | notElem y lista=[lista]
    | otherwise=isMatch:(my_split rest y)
    where 
    (isMatch,rest)=break (==y) lista
```

The only part that's different is the break condition and it really seems to me it should do the same thing...plus the first function form should ensure i don't get to add empty lists to my result forever...Sorry about the noobish question and thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
GOA> break (=='c') "abcde"
("ab","cde")
GOA> break (=='c') "cde"
("","cde")
GOA>
```

`break` doesn't strip off the character it matches.

Answer (score 3):

```
break p xs = (takeWhile (not . p) xs, dropWhile (not . p) xs)
```

In your first version that works, you apply `tail` to the result of `dropWhile`.

In your second version that doesn't work, you don't do this.

Answer (score 2):

As others have explained, break returns the pair of takeWhile and dropWhile. You want to take the tail of the dropWhile. You can do it like this:

```
where 
(isMatch,_:rest)=break (==y) lista
```